# ASP core + Angular solution doesn't launch in VS unless full clean/rebuild

Tags: angular, visual-studio, asp.net-core

I am developing a web application using ASP Core 3.1 with web API controllers + an Angular 11 front-end.

Most of the time when I run the solution it doesn't launch properly. It opens the browser, which will show me a spinner and then will display the message:

{"StatusCode":500,"Message":"Internal Server Error."}

This is 'fixed' by doing a full clean and rebuild of the solution. The next launch will make the website pop up correctly. The launch after that will give me the error message again until I do another clean and rebuild.

This behavior started happening when the front-end was upgraded from Angular 9 to 11.

Also, might be a related symptom: launching the solution is extremely slow. It can take multiple minutes on a powerful machine before it shows anything in the browser, the website or the error message.

I have no idea where to start looking. Since the clean/rebuild-workaround 'works' it does not seem to be the code itself. However, I would love to find a solution because it slows down development.

Comment: I suggest you could try to delete the bin folder and try again.

Comment: @BrandoZhang that has the same effect. It will work on the next first launch, but will no longer work next launch.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

More of a workaround than a solution:

This issue does not occur when debugging using the project launch configuration instead of the IIS Express launch configuration.

Since I switched I've had no more problems.